# Adding circle markers on leaflet R on to a map already plotted

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

```
bins <- c(0,10,20,30,40,50,Inf)

pal <- colorNumeric(
palette = c('Grey', '#C9E1F9', '#BCD2E8', '#86ACC6', '#73A5C6', '#528AAE', '#2E5984',  '#1E3F66', '#152B46'),
domain = ar_prov_objetivos$Orden
)

 ar_prov_objetivos%>%mutate(popup= str_c('<strong>', ProvinciaMod, '<strong>',
                  ' - Toneladas de IA: ', Potencial)%>%
       map(htmltools::HTML))%>%
  leaflet()%>%
   addTiles()%>%
    addPolygons(label = ~popup,
          fillColor = ~pal(Orden),
          color = 'black',
          weight = 0.5,
          smoothFactor = 0.5,
          opacity = 1,
          fillOpacity = 0.55,
          highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'white',
                                              weight = 2,
                                              bringToFront = TRUE),
          labelOptions=labelOptions(
            style = list('font-weight' = 'normal', padding = '3px 8px'),
            textsize = '15px',
            direction = 'auto'))%>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = -62.3964567,
               lat = -38.721146,
               radius = 10)%>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = -61.2364567,
               lat = -43.725146,
               radius = 10)%>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = -78.3964567,
               lat = -34.724146,
               radius = 10)
```

Comment: I would like to add Circle Markers like in the last 3, still not possible.

Comment: First, we need some of your data to help.  Can you edit your question to include some of the data, using `dput`?   Second, I would break up this command into a few parts.  Build your data file, create your main leaflet map and save it as a separate object, and then add new layers to that object.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thank you Ben

Comment: Could you add your solution to your question. That can help other people who find your question via a search.